# virtualenv error for another python version

Tags: python, virtualenv, redhat

I'm getting this error when I try to setup virtualenv for a version of python other than my system default:

```
-sh-4.1$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 test
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 9, in <module>
    import struct
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
```

System is RedHat and default system python version is 2.6.6. Any help would be much appreciated.